# Square-connect example function gives a ".then is not a function" error

Tags: square-connect

After installing square-connect and running the test code I see:

api.listLocations.then is not a function

node -v
v9.4.0

Is there anything special I need to do that's not in the install instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the example code you read (thanks for bringing that to our attention!). It will be fixed whenever [this pull request](https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/pull/11) gets merged.

Instead of `api.listLocations.then(function(data) {` you should use `api.listLocations().then(function(data) {`